# Matplotlib : How to save dataframe and graph in the same pdf?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf

```
data = {'name': ['Ram', 'john', 'tom', 'rocky'],'salary':[2000, 4000, 2500, 6000]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.plot(kind ='line')
```

I want to save the plot in pdf and I also want to save the dataframe in the same pdf. How can I do that ? Please suggest.

Comment: Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Maybe with [matplotlib table](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.table.html) to convert the dataframe to matplotlib text? Here'a [demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/table_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-misc-table-demo-py).  It would only work when there isn't too much data.

Comment: Can you show us what you already tried to do?